# Expected class-name before '{' token

Tags: c++, codeblocks

When trying to compile my project this header file (Bobjr) code::blocks gives me the error Expected class-name before  '{' token. What is wrong with this code?

```
#ifndef BOBJR_H
#define BOBJR_H


class Bobjr: public Bob
{
    public:
        Bobjr();
};

#endif // BOBJR_H
```

This is the Bobjr cpp:

```
#include "Bobjr.h"
#include "Bob.h"
#include <iostream>

Bobjr::Bobjr()
{
    //ctor
}
```

Comment: Bob jr. needs more parenting :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a definition for `Bob`.  You either need it in the same header of you need to `#include` the header that declares `Bob` before declaring `Bobjr`

Comment: Do I need to include it in the header file as well? Because the .cpp file already has Bob included.

Comment: Yes, you need it in the header too.  This is needed for example if `Bobjr` is instantiated from a different source file or subclassed elsewhere

Comment: @ArthurDent: Anything that refers to the name `Bob` must be able to see `Bob`'s declaration. Otherwise the compiler has no way of knowing even that `Bob` is a class.